Pandas Dataframe Multiindex - Calculate Mean and add additional column to each level of the index
Given the following dataframe:
Year     2024          2023          2022
Header   N Result SD   N Result SD   N Result SD
Vendor
A        5 20     3    5 22     4    1 21     3
B        4 25     2    4 25     3    4 26     5
C        9 22     3    9 27     1    3 23     3   
D        3 23     5    3 16     2    5 13     4 
E        5 27     2    5 21     3    3 19     5

I would like to calculate for each year the mean value of the results column and then create a column, where the relative deviation to the mean is displayed (e.g. Results Value / mean-value * 100). The N and SD column were just included for completeness and is not needed for the calculation.
Year     2024                    2023                      2022
Header   N Result SD Deviation   N Result SD Deviation     N Result SD Deviation
Vendor
A        5 20     3  85.5        5 22     4  99.1          1 21     3  ..
B        4 25     2  106         4 25     3  113           4 26     5  ..
C        9 22     3  ..          9 27     1  ..            3 23     3  .. 
D        3 23     5  ..          3 16     2  ..            5 13     4  ..
E        5 27     2  ..          5 21     3  ..            3 19     5  ..

How what i be able to achieve that?
Thanks a lot in advance!

to make your code more reproducible, could you please provide the input DataFrame as code (using df.to_dict('tight')). This is much easier to load DataFrames with a  MultiIndex.

Use DataFrame.xs for select Result labels in MultiIndex, divide by mean and append to original in concat, last for correct position add DataFrame.sort_index with parameter sort_remaining=False:
df1 = df.xs('Result', axis=1, level=1, drop_level=False)

out = (pd.concat([df, 
                 df1.div(df1.mean()).mul(100)
                    .rename(columns={'Result':'Deviation'})], axis=1)
         .sort_index(axis=1, ascending=False, level=0, sort_remaining=False))
print (out)
  2024                       2023                       2022            \
     N Result SD   Deviation    N Result SD   Deviation    N Result SD   
A    5     20  3   85.470085    5     22  4   99.099099    1     21  3   
B    4     25  2  106.837607    4     25  3  112.612613    4     26  5   
C    9     22  3   94.017094    9     27  1  121.621622    3     23  3   
D    3     23  5   98.290598    3     16  2   72.072072    5     13  4   
E    5     27  2  115.384615    5     21  3   94.594595    3     19  5   

               
    Deviation  
A  102.941176  
B  127.450980  
C  112.745098  
D   63.725490  
E   93.137255  

Another loop idea:
for x in df.columns.levels[0]:
    df[(x, 'Deviation')] = df[(x, 'Result')].div(df[(x, 'Result')].mean()).mul(100)

out = df.sort_index(axis=1, ascending=False, level=0, sort_remaining=False)
print (out)
  2024                       2023                       2022            \
     N Result SD   Deviation    N Result SD   Deviation    N Result SD   
A    5     20  3   85.470085    5     22  4   99.099099    1     21  3   
B    4     25  2  106.837607    4     25  3  112.612613    4     26  5   
C    9     22  3   94.017094    9     27  1  121.621622    3     23  3   
D    3     23  5   98.290598    3     16  2   72.072072    5     13  4   
E    5     27  2  115.384615    5     21  3   94.594595    3     19  5   

               
    Deviation  
A  102.941176  
B  127.450980  
C  112.745098  
D   63.725490  
E   93.137255  


That was quick. Thanks a lot for the help! Works like a charm.

You can use xs to select the results, then perform your computation and concat to the original DataFrame with reordering of the columns using sort_index and a stable sort:
# select Result
res = df.xs('Result', level='Header', axis=1)

# compute the deviation
tmp = (pd.concat({'Deviation': res.div(res.mean()).mul(100).round(2)},
                 names=['Header'], axis=1)
         .swaplevel(axis=1)
      )

# combine to original dataset
out = (pd.concat([df, tmp], axis=1)
         .sort_index(ascending=False, axis=1, level=0,
                     sort_remaining=False, kind='stable')
      )

Or, using reshaping with stack/unstack and groupby.transform:
out = (df.stack('Year', sort=False)
         .assign(Deviation=lambda x: x['Result'].div(x.groupby('Year')['Result']
                                                     .transform('mean')
                                                    ).mul(100).round(2))
         .unstack('Year').swaplevel(axis=1)
         .sort_index(ascending=False, axis=1, level=0,
                     sort_remaining=False, kind='stable')
      )

Output:
Year   2024                     2023                     2022                    
Header    N Result SD Deviation    N Result SD Deviation    N Result SD Deviation
Vendor                                                                           
A         5     20  3     85.47    5     22  4     99.10    1     21  3    102.94
B         4     25  2    106.84    4     25  3    112.61    4     26  5    127.45
C         9     22  3     94.02    9     27  1    121.62    3     23  3    112.75
D         3     23  5     98.29    3     16  2     72.07    5     13  4     63.73
E         5     27  2    115.38    5     21  3     94.59    3     19  5     93.14

